# How to calculate binomial distributions

Tags: probability, logistic, python, binomial-distribution

I have a dataset containing election results in 560 areas (exact % and I converted them into 1/0 - won/lost variable).
I would like to calculate binomial distributions for the 560 areas. In binomial we need to use following parameters: p, r and n.What numbers do i 'plug in' to calculate the binomial distribution?
I use the binom in python:

from scipy.stats import binom
data_binom = binom.rvs(n=560,p=0.50,r=50000)

and when i plot i get the frequencies on both axes not the probabilities for winning withing the 0-1 bounds...
[image]
What do I need to correct ?

Comment: possibly duplicate https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447299/calculate-a-binomial-in-python-to-determine-the-probability

Comment: Not sure which version of scipy you are using, assuming your r is the size parameter, for example binom.rvs(n=560, p=0.90, size=2) could give you for example, array([507, 509]), it means 90 percent of the areas would have success rate in general, size will tell you how many times to repeat the trial

Comment: Simulating from binomial distribution won't tell you which ones are win/lose but overall proportion of wins (success).

Comment: Thank you for your patience Mehmet Suzen!